# Laravel - how to see source of queries?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I know you can log queries in Laravel.  But I'm wondering if there's a way to also log **the name of the script that ran the query**.  So for instance, if an `update` query was logged, I'd like to also know that it was initiated by `PostController.php`.

I'm working on a very large application that uses hundreds of queries, and when I need to remove one, it's very difficult to locate where that query is coming from.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think of make an syntax error with my SQL, to identify the caller from exception stack, kind of debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [`Connection::logQuery()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php), each database query triggers a [QueryExecuted](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Events/QueryExecuted.php) event.

You could [listen to this event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#listening-for-query-events), and use [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to crawl up the function calls.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::listen(function ($query) {

    // send this to a log or whatever
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

    // also, you can read $query to get the SQL string, bindings...
});
```

The main work will probably be to filter the data, to isolate what you are looking for.